# How to add elements to an array? swift

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

everybody! I've just started learning swift so sorry if the question is dumb. I want to add values to an array "uu" using a loop. However every time it just overwrites "uu".

Pls help, thanks!

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXLQw.png)

Comment: use `append` property ...and post code rather then image

Comment: var Array = Array(repeating: "uu", count: 13)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is simple as

```
uu.append(newNumber)
```